# What is my free reward from Cassius Ryder in The Gig?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I am the shop of Cassius Ryder and I am supposed to collect a free reward. Yet I don't know what my reward is and since his inventory is rather large I don't know what I am supposed to pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to get the Tattoo: Tyger Claws Dermal Imprint that will allow you to make proper use of smart weapons (allows use of smart-targeting).

You'll find it under the category: Hands.

[image: Inventory at Cassius Ryder on HANDS to get Tattoo for proper smart weapon usage]

Comment: They don't show up for me and I can not finish this mission :(